# Does the weather affect elemental damage, creature strengths and behavior?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

Do the weather effects in Final Fantasy XIV: a Realm Reborn affect elemental damage, creature strengths and behavior?

I recall that in Final Fantasy XII, weather played an important role in elemental damage, the spawn rate of elementals and entities, and also the behavior of specific monsters.

Comment: Do you mean Final Fantasy XI, not XII? I know FFXI had special conditions relating to weather

Comment: @Dycker Final Fantasy XII did have weather affects and i think some weather patterns did affect Magiks (like in Giza the Wet would amplify lighting spells) however the most noticeable affect of it was different enemies appearing, Mainly the appearance of Elementals and Entities....ofcase weather was limited to each area such as the Sandsea would have sandstorms, Giza and Ozmone Plains would be wet, Jydg's would have more Myst hanging around and you could switch between Ozmone and Giza and see it suddenly chnage in Giza from Wet to Dry

Comment: @Dycker Memor-X is correct. I was actually talking about FFXII as I remember I used to take massive advantages on the weather to amplify my damage output and one-shot most mobs I encountered.

Hence I ask if there is any benefits to gain from ffxiv's weather ( Though my first instinct says no, because the traditional "elemental ring" doesn't seem to be in play (where lightning is weak to water and vice versa). The only class with elemental diversity is THM/BLK, and weapons don't have elemental affinities. Armor does have elemental resistances though

Keeping the question up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No to combat. It would be certainly neat if it did though.

Partial Yes to spawns now, some special mobs only appear during certain weather conditions (iirc, its only Odin and his lightning weather atm, but I seem to remember something requiring the gloom weather).

It does also affect fishing, even more so with the highend fish (stupid raincaller), and greatly so with the recently added "Big Fish." The Sightseeing Log also usually requires that you visit each vista during a specific type of weather and time-of-day.

The 2.35 update (Aug 19, 2014) added "Skywatcher" NPCs that will give you an in-game weather forecast for the next 8, 16, and 24 hours (Eorzea time).

Comment: I think the causation of the Odin weather ("Hopelessness") is backwards, in that all Black Shroud zones switch to Hopelessness weather whenever Odin spawns, and not before (and never otherwise). Other than that, though, this all seems correct. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yeah, it was the Hopelessness, not gloom, my bad. Too many games, to make years of gaming to keep it all straight. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: During FFXIV 1.0, there actually was a different monster that would only spawn during "Gloom" weather in Mor Dhona, to add to the confusion :P

Comment: Yay, not insane!

Answer (score 1):

Played this game for more than two weeks, and it would seem **No**.

Weather has no significant effect in combat.